# Prove by induction that $4$ divides $n^3+(n+1)^3+(n+2)^3+(n+3)^3$

Tags: proof-verification, induction

Just looking for someone to check my work and for feedback, thanks!

---

Base case: $n=0$

$0+1+8+27 = 36$

$4$ divides $36.$

---

Inductive step: Assume $4$ divides $k^3+(k+1)^3+(k+2)^3+(k+3)^3$ for some number where $k$ is a natural number including zero. So $k^3+(k+1)^3+(k+2)^3+(k+3)^3 = 4b$ where $b$ is some integer. We need to show $4$ divides $(k+1)^3+(k+2)^3+(k+3)^3+(k+4)^3$.
\begin{align}
(k+1)^3 & +(k+2)^3+(k+3)^3+(k+4)^3\\ 
&= 4k^3+30k^2+90k+100\\
&=(k^3+(k+1)^3+(k+2)^3+(k+3)^3)+12k^2+48k+36\\
&=4b+12k^2+48k+36 \qquad \text{(by inductive hypothesis)}\\
&=4(b+3k^2+12k+9)
\end{align}

Since $b$ is an element of any integer this holds true for $(k+1)$. Hence proven.

Comment: If you did all of your algebra correctly, then I think it looks OK. It could be communicated more clearly (that is, it could be more polished), but the core elements are there in terms of correctness.

Comment: Seems all correct

Comment: Seems correct, but a suggestion to simplify: you don't need to expand the whole thing, because obviously$$(k+1)^3+(k+2)^3+(k+3)^3+(k+4)^3=\bigl(    k^3+(k+1)^3+(k+2)^3+(k+3     )^3\bigr)           +\bigl((k+4)^3-k^3\bigr)$$and you only need to expand the last bit.

Comment: The induction step amounts to showing $(k+4)^3-k^3$ is divisible by $4$. This is obvious, since $a-b$ divides $a^3-b^3$.

Comment: You need just to show $30k^2+90k\equiv 0$ mod(4) which implies $2k^2+2k\equiv 0$ mod(4) i.e. $2k(k+1)\equiv 0$ mod(4) which is clear.

Comment: DO NOT delete stuff out of the body of your own post like this. It is bad form and against the spirit of the site.

Comment: There is an algebra error in the proof. The term $36$ (which appears at the far right after two of the equality signs) should be $64$, so the $9$ at the end of the last equation should be $16$. The difference between the incorrect calculation and the correct calculation is itself a multiple of $4$, which is why the proof _seems_ to work. (By the way, I spotted the error because there was reason to believe that $(k+4)^3 - k^3$ would appear somehow in the proof, and the constant term of that expression is $64$.)

Answer (score 5):

Your answer seems right and looks like a short route, I would use modules to avoid the algebra but it wouldn't be induction.
For $K \equiv 0 \pmod 4$ the modules of $4$ for the elements of the equation would be $0^3 + 1^3 + 2^3 + (-1)^3 \equiv 0 + 1 + 0 + (-1) = 0 \pmod 4$.
And because there are always $4$ consecutive elements, the four module values are going to be the same for any $K$.

Comment: [See this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to write math formulas on this site.

Answer (score 3):

To go from
$n$ to $n+1$,
you subtract $n^3$
and add $(n+4)^3$.
This means that
the sum changes by
$(n+4)^3 - n^3$,
so if this is divisible by 4,
divisibility by 4 remains.

But
$(n+4)^3 - n^3
=(n^3+12n^2+48n+64)-n^3
=12n^2+48n+64
=4(3n^2+12n+16)
$
*is* divisible by 4.

Since the first sum
(for n=0)
is
$0^3+1^3+2^3+3^3
=1+8+27
=36
$
is divisible by 4,
all are divisible by 4.